# Get more verbose message when something fails in Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am curious about the way in which Sonata Admin handle and displays error messages as I need them to be a little more descriptive. For instance when the message comes from DB because a constraint fails I got a message like this:

> An error has occurred during update of item "Media Title Test".

But if I leave a required field empty the error is the same. I want to know if it's possible to handle this in some way in order to be more descriptive. Any advice or help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass validation rules and message using Constraint in your entity.

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Author.php

// ...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Choice(
     *     choices = { "male", "female", "other" },
     *     message = "Choose a valid gender."
     * )
     */
    public $gender;

    // ...
}
```

[Validation Constraints Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html) will give you a full list of constraint available by default in Symfony.

Comment: Okey, that works perfectly and do what I want but how do I remove the annoying dot (I assume is kind of UL) on the message list? ([see this image for info](http://content.screencast.com/users/ReynierPM/folders/Snagit/media/ca8f6d93-dda3-4f50-8dd1-7a5df8e25749/10.23.2015-10.48.png))

Comment: @ReynierPM These validation error messages are shown using error template. It uses <ul> to show each error message. Quick solution would be using css to hide or customize that dot.